# SQL Server - Select between 2 dates of type DD/MM/YYYY

Tags: sql-server

I want to query a datetime field using a range of dates provided in the format DD/MM/YYYY.

I know that to convert datetime to a DD/MM/YYYY format that I can use:

```
CONVERT(CARCHAR(10), ORDERDATE,103)`
```

And this works fine when querying a single date, eg:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
CONVERT(DATE, ORDERDATE),
CONVERT(CARCHAR(10), ORDERDATE,103)
FROM ORDERS
WHERE CONVERT(CARCHAR(10), ORDERDATE,103) = '19/10/2017'
```

Returns: `2017-10-19, 19/10/2017`

However it does not work on a **range** of dates, eg:

```
WHERE CONVERT(CARCHAR(10), ORDERDATE,103) BETWEEN '17/10/2017' AND '19/10/2017'
```

Returns:

```
2014-02-05
2016-12-12
2013-04-30
```

I know there are hundreds of threads about SQL dates, but they all seem to be regarding reformatting the output and not preparing the input.  Do I need to reformat my DD/MM/YYYY inputs?

Comment: You should convert your `char`/`varchar` inputs to `date` for the comparison rather than converting a `date` to `char`/`varchar`.

Comment: There is not such `type` as dd/mm/yyyy. A date is... a `date`.

Comment: Yes sorry they are not of 'type' DD/MM/YYYY, they are in the 'format' DD/MM/YYYY.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To query a range of dates, use the `DATE`-datatype instead of `VARCHAR`.

If datatype of column `ORDERDATE` is `DATETIME`:

```
WHERE CONVERT(DATE, ORDERDATE) BETWEEN
CONVERT(DATE, '17/10/2017', 103) AND CONVERT(DATE, '19/10/2017', 103)
```

The conversion of `ORDERDATE` is **only** necessary if the start and end date are the same. (in this case, when no conversion is done, only dates with a time value of '00:00:00.000' will be returned)

**EDIT:**

To omit the conversion of `ORDERDATE` you can add the time to the dates and convert them to `DATETIME` instead of `DATE`, like this:

```
WHERE ORDERDATE BETWEEN
CONVERT(DATETIME, '19/10/2017 00:00:00') AND CONVERT(DATETIME, '19/10/2017 23:59:59.999');
```

Or even simpler, like suggested in @Used_By_Already's answer:

```
WHERE ORDERDATE >= '20171017' AND ORDERDATE < '20171020' --Note the end date is here +1 day
```

Comment: `CONVERT(DATE, '17/10/2017')` can fail if you omit the style number

Comment: why converting ? Zero added value, and it defeats optimisation and indexes

Comment: @PatrickHonorez Convert, because OP wrote that data-type of `ORDERDATE` is datetime. If you don't convert, only dates with a time value of '00:00:00.000' are returned.

Comment: Great, thanks MatSnow.  Now using  `WHERE CONVERT(DATE,ORDERDATE)  >= CONVERT(DATE, '17/10/2017',103) AND CONVERT(DATE,ORDERDATE)  <= CONVERT(DATE, '19/10/2017',103)

Comment: @MatSnow the problem is in `WHERE CONVERT(DATE, ORDERDATE)`. I really think converting the field  - when you can avoid that - is bad practice. I always do like suggested by @Used_By_Already

Comment: @PatrickHonorez I know, i wasnt specific enough. Already edited my answer some minutes ago. And i totally agree to Used_By_Already's suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server **date information** should NOT be stored "in a format". If if they are literally stored in that format then they are NOT dates as far as the database is concerned (they are "strings" that look like dates) and you will have a nightmare to deal with if they are DD/MM/YYYY because they simply will not behave like dates should.

There are several specific **data types** in SQL Server for date/time information (**datetime, datetime2, smalldatetime, date, time**) but ALL of these do not store data in a human readable format at all. Instead they **stored as groups of numbers**, which will be displayed in a human readable manner, and in your case - by default - you are seeing then in DD/MM/YYYY format. A user in China might prefer to see a date in YYYY.MM.DD or in the USA as MM/DD/YYYY. This is possible because a human format is applied on top of the numbers that are stored before they get displayed.

So. In SQL Server there is a "safe" date literal in the form of 'YYYYMMDD' and this may be used without the need to CONVERT or CAST:

**IF** your `[ORDERDATE]` column is a date (or smalldatetime/datetime/datetime2) then this will work:

```
WHERE ORDERDATE BETWEEN '20171017' AND '20171019'
```

OR, you may explicitly convert a string to but you need a "style number" to be present to make these fully reliable. Style 103 for example is for `DD/MM/YYYY`

```
WHERE ORDERDATE BETWEEN CONVERT(date, '17/10/2017',103) AND CONVERT(date, '19/10/2017',103)
```

---

Although "between" has been used in the discussion above a far more reliable method of forming date ranges is to NOT use "between", instead do it this way:

```
WHERE ORDERDATE >= '20171017' AND ORDERDATE < '20171020'
```

With this pattern (note the second day is now +1) it does not matter which date precision is stored in the column. For example, see [Bad habits to kick : mis-handling date / range queries](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries)

Comment: Correct style number for `'20171017'` is `112` not `103`. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql

Comment: thanks my proof reading failed, I was trying to specifically use dd/mm/yyy (now fixed). nb if using YYYMMDD literals (style 112) then you don't need to explicitly convert (as in my first example)

Comment: Only, the last example works. Because `ORDERDATE` is datatype `DATETIME`, only dates with a time value of '00:00:00.000' are returned

Comment: best practice is to avoid use of functions on the data, so my advice is to use a range anyway, but **date may be compared to datetime** so it does work, remember I am NOT advocating use of convert, merely showing it might be used. also you could convert to datetime if you prefer

Comment: Sorry i was not specific enough. I mean it won't work when the start and end date are the same. (i know, it is only theoretical)

Comment: Thanks Used_By_Already, although as stated in my post, the field ORDERDATE is datetime so no problem there.It is my inputs which are in dd/mm/yyyy and I wanted to know if I first needed to re-jig the strings before applying to my query or if I could use an SQL function.  MatSnow's solution to convert the inputs to date using style 103 works fine.